# Power BI Web.Contents Failing In A Function But Not Outside

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

as ever - greatful for help from the commuinity.

The following is my code to call an API, initReq, which if not null goes to gatherpagingdata.
gatherpagingdata uses a URL that changes and is gathered from uri = initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] and then in the gatherpagingdata function nextPageUrl = newReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl]. I have checked that both uri as text, headers are been passed through as text and I have also checked that nextpagefunc, textBeforePaging and textAfterPaging coming through as text as best I can as they are then used in newReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(textBeforePaging, [Headers=headers, Query=[paging=textAfterPaging]])).

With that in mind I can not see why this is failing to work correctly and is the source of the error below.

I have a feeling its going to be some thing I have not considered when trying to run a non dynamic URL in side a function as it seems to work out side of it.

Any help you have to give would be appreciated.

T

```
let
    // NB Making calls to multiple instances from the same Power BI Dash can cause problems with authentication
    // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fstsQMZiHME
    // check data source security

    // Common parameters
    queryStringApiIntegrationCodevar = "xxxxxx",
    queryStringUserNamevar = "xxxxxxxxx",
    queryStringUserSecretvar = "xxxxxxxx",
    queryStringContentTypevar = "application/json",
    
    headers = [
        #"ApiIntegrationCode"=queryStringApiIntegrationCodevar,
        #"UserName"=queryStringUserNamevar,
        #"Secret"=queryStringUserSecretvar,
        #"Content-Type"=queryStringContentTypevar
    ],

    apiUrl = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query",
    apiUrlnew = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query/next",
    searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""op"":""gte"",""field"":""id"",""value"":""0""}]}",

    // Functions
    converturl = (data as text) as text => 
        let
            out = Uri.Parts("http://contoso?a=" & Text.Replace(data, "&", "%26"))[Query][a]
        in
            out,

    gatherpagingdata = (data as list, uri as text, headers) =>
        let
            // Get the Data
            // Replace Percent URL-encoded characters
            nextpagefunc = converturl(uri) as text,        
            textBeforePaging = Text.BeforeDelimiter(nextpagefunc, "?paging=") as text,
            textAfterPaging = Text.BetweenDelimiters(nextpagefunc, "?paging=", " ") as text,

            newReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(textBeforePaging, [Headers=headers, Query=[paging=textAfterPaging]])),
            newdata = newReq[items],

            // Add that data to rolling aggregate
            updatedData = List.Combine({data, newdata}),

            // Check for the next URL using function
            nextPageUrl = newReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl],

            // If there's no next page of data, return. If there is, call @gatherpagingdata again to get more data
            result = if nextPageUrl <> null then @gatherpagingdata(updatedData, nextPageUrl, headers) else updatedData
        in
            result,

    // Execute
    initReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, [Headers=headers, Query=[search=searchFilter]])) otherwise error "Failed to retrieve data from the API 1st Pass",
    initData = initReq[items],

    // Before we call gather(), we want to see if it's even necessary.
    // First request returns only one page? Return.
    // OutputList = try if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then initData else gather(initData, BaseURI) otherwise error uri,
    uri = initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl],

    // Decode the extracted value
    // Replace Percent URL-encoded characters
    nextpagefunc = converturl(uri),

    outputList = 
        if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then 
            initData 
        else 
            gatherpagingdata(initData, uri, headers),

    // Then place records into a table. This will expand all columns available in the record.
    expand = Table.FromRecords(outputList)
in
    expand
```

Error:

> DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from
> 'https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query/next?paging=%7B%22pageSize%22%3A500%2C%22previousIds%22%3A%5B3%5D%2C%22nextIds%22%3A%5B593%5D%7D%26search%3D%7B%22filter%22%3A%5B%7B%22op%22%3A%22gte%22%2C%22field%22%3A%22id%22%2C%22value%22%3A%220%22%7D%5D%7D'
> (405): Method Not Allowed Details:
> DataSourceKind=Web
> DataSourcePath=https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query/next
> Url=https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query/next?paging=%7B%22pageSize%22%3A500%2C%22previousIds%22%3A%5B3%5D%2C%22nextIds%22%3A%5B593%5D%7D%26search%3D%7B%22filter%22%3A%5B%7B%22op%22%3A%22gte%22%2C%22field%22%3A%22id%22%2C%22value%22%3A%220%22%7D%5D%7D

Working code:

```
let
    // NB Making calls to multiple instances from the same Power BI Dash can cause problems with authentication
    // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fstsQMZiHME
    // check data source security

    // Common parameters
    queryStringApiIntegrationCodevar = "xxxxx",
    queryStringUserNamevar = "xxxxx",
    queryStringUserSecretvar = "xxxxx",
    queryStringContentTypevar = "application/json",
    
    headers = [
        #"ApiIntegrationCode"=queryStringApiIntegrationCodevar,
        #"UserName"=queryStringUserNamevar,
        #"Secret"=queryStringUserSecretvar,
        #"Content-Type"=queryStringContentTypevar
    ],

    apiUrl = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query",
    apiUrlnew = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query/next",
    searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""op"":""gte"",""field"":""id"",""value"":""0""}]}",

    // Functions
    converturl = (data as text) as text => 
        let
            out = Uri.Parts("http://contoso?a=" & Text.Replace(data, "&", "%26"))[Query][a]
        in
            out,

    gatherpagingdata = (data as list, uri as text, headers, searchFilter) =>
        let
            // Get the Data
            // Replace Percent URL-encoded characters
            nextpagefunc = converturl(uri) as text,        
            textBeforePaging = Text.BeforeDelimiter(nextpagefunc, "?paging=") as text,
            textAfterPagingandBeforesearch = Text.BetweenDelimiters(nextpagefunc, "?paging=", "&search=") as text,
            textAfterPagingandsearchEquals = Text.BetweenDelimiters(nextpagefunc, "&search=", " ") as text,
            // pull out search filter

            newReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(textBeforePaging, [Headers=headers, Query=[paging=textAfterPagingandBeforesearch , search=textAfterPagingandsearchEquals]])),
            newdata = newReq[items],

            // Add that data to rolling aggregate
            updatedData = List.Combine({data, newdata}),

            // Check for the next URL using function
            nextPageUrl = newReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl],

            // If there's no next page of data, return. If there is, call @gatherpagingdata again to get more data
            result = if nextPageUrl <> null then @gatherpagingdata(updatedData, nextPageUrl, headers , searchFilter) else updatedData
        in
            result,

    // Execute
    
    apiUrltest = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query/next",
    searchFiltertest = "{""pageSize"":500,""previousIds"":[3],""nextIds"":[593]}",
    searchFiltertest2 = "{""filter"":[{""op"":""gte"",""field"":""id"",""value"":""0""}]}",

    //initReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, [Headers=headers, Query=[search=searchFilter]])) otherwise error "Failed to retrieve data from the API 1st Pass",
    initReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrltest, [Headers=headers, Query=[paging=searchFiltertest, search=searchFilter ]])) otherwise error "Failed to retrieve data from the API 1st Pass",
    initData = initReq[items],

    // Before we call gather(), we want to see if it's even necessary.
    // First request returns only one page? Return.
    // OutputList = try if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then initData else gather(initData, BaseURI) otherwise error uri,
    uri = initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl],

    // Decode the extracted value
    // Replace Percent URL-encoded characters
    nextpagefunc = converturl(uri),

    outputList = 
        if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then 
            initData 
        else 
            gatherpagingdata(initData, uri, headers , searchFilter),

    // Then place records into a table. This will expand all columns available in the record.
    expand = Table.FromRecords(outputList)
in
    expand
```

Comment: This isn't a PQ bug. The request sent returns an error from the server. Paste the url in a browser: https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query/next?paging=%7B%22pageSize%22%3A500%2C%22previousIds%22%3A%5B3%5D%2C%22nextIds%22%3A%5B593%5D%7D%26search%3D%7B%22filter%22%3A%5B%7B%22op%22%3A%22gte%22%2C%22field%22%3A%22id%22%2C%22value%22%3A%220%22%7D%5D%7D

Comment: Hi - I've checked the url manually from uri = initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl], nextpagefunc = converturl(uri) as text, textBeforePaging & textAfterPaging as the url comes from the last page received. I have also tested on Postman. I'm wondering if its how the query elements are been passed over.

Answer (score 0):

Problem found... rather than sending the whole Query string in one go I had to split and resend.

The fault was as a result showing the URL correct but in reality not processing right as a result.

Updated code on first post.

Thanks all